# Android emulator without Studio launch error

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to install just the Android Emulator on my Mac, not the whole Android Studio.

So far I have:

1) Installed Android-SDK via Homebrew

```
brew cask install android-sdk
```

2)  Added to my $PATH, and checked I have no other ANDROID related PATHS going on.

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/usr/local/share/android-sdk"
```

3) In terminal running

```
$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
```

shows

```
 /usr/local/share/android-sdk: is a directory
```

4) Created a new AVD in with AVDManager.
5) Try to run created AVD and get this error

```
PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/usr/local/share/android-sdk]!
```

I also can't run 'emulator' from the command line, I CAN run avdmanager and sdkmanager fine.

I've checked the path which appears to be correct. The AVD is in the location of

```
/Users/<user>/.android/avd/test.avd
```

Where could I be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Linux, trying to build a Docker image for the emulator, and finally find out what the reason was by looking at the Android emulator source code.

I installed only the required SDK packages for emulator ("emulator" and one of the "system-images"), but the emulator program check if ANDROID_HOME or ANDROID_SDK_ROOT path contains the "platforms" and "platform-tools" directory, so I installed the "platform-tools" package and one of the "platforms" package and it worked.

Manually create those two empty directories should also be enough.

Comment: On my installation (macOS) I have those two directories, and still no luck.